# Cannot Find Image

Tags: java, image, swing

I'm having a problem where I can't find images through Java. My friend and I are working on a project and we've done the exact same things. I've changed the paths to the location of the images and even dragged/dropped the images into Eclipse. However, I've had no luck. Here's my code:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class MapArray {
    static JPanel[][] tiles = new JPanel[30][29];
    static String[][] images = new String[30][30];
    final static int SIZE = 30;
    static int place=0;

public MapArray(){

}

protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
    java.net.URL imgURL = Map.class.getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}

public static void setMap(){

    try {
        String a = getFileContents("C:\\Users\\*****\\workspace\\Pokemon\\src\\map1.txt");
        for(int x=0; x<29; x++){
            for(int y=0; y<30; y++){
                images[x][y]=a.substring(0,a.indexOf(" "));
                a=a.substring(a.indexOf(" ")+1);
                System.out.println(images[x][y]);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("y u no work :(");
    }

}

public static String getFileContents(String fileName) throws Exception {
    File theFile = new File(fileName);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) theFile.length()];
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(theFile);
    int m = 0, n = 0;
    while (m < bytes.length) {
        n = in.read(bytes, m, bytes.length - m);
        m += n;
    }
    in.close();
    return new String(bytes); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            setMap();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(30, 29, 0, 0));
            for (int i = 0; i < 29; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 29; j++) {
                    tiles[i][j] = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
                    tiles[i][j].add(new JLabel(
                            createImageIcon("C:\\Users\\*****\\workspace\\Pokemon\\src\\tile"+"-"+images[i][j]+".png")));
                    frame.add(tiles[i][j]);
                }
            }
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}


}
```

Everything I've tried with putting in the full image path doesn't work. Also, would anyone be able to help with relative paths? My friend and I will be sharing code between multiple computers so relative paths that aren't dedicated on where our workspace is located would be great. Thanks!

Comment: could you maybe post some output so we have some idea what does and doesn't work?

Comment: Couldn't find file: C:\Users\___\workspace\Pokemon\src\tile-24.png

Comment: That's just one example of it. It can read from the text file but it can't find the images that I'm 100% are in that exact location.

Comment: Since this worked yesterday (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003610/gridlayout-removing-padding-between-jpanels) something is different - are you 100% sure that you have the capitalization correct?

Comment: The problem is that that worked on my friend's computer. The images still didn't show up on mine. Everything works fine for my friend but the images can't be found for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// get resource of *your* class, instead of Java's Map.class
MapArray.class.getResource(path);
...
String a = getFileContents("map1.txt"); // local path, not absolute
```

**and** put the file to your `src` folder, next to the `MapArray.java` file.

```
src/
 |-- MapArray.java
 |-- ...
 `-- map1.txt
```

`map1.txt` will be moved into `bin` directory, next to `.class` file (bin/ is hidden in Eclipse by default, but that's where the classpath is set). Later you'll also want to make sure that the resource file is packaged into `.jar`.

Comment: path = "map1.txt". Just the base name of the file, without any preceding directories. It means *look next to the `.class` file, wherever it is*.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you'll need to change `getFileContents(String path)` method. Inside it call `MapArray.class.getResourceAsStream(path)` and convert the stream into a `String` - [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1763849/703503) a sample how.

Answer (score 1):

> would anyone be able to help with relative paths?

```
String a = getFileContents("./src/map1.txt");
```

Comment: That still doesn't seem to fix the problem with the images not being found. I can assure you that they're in the right locations. I've taken the exact error message: "Couldn't find file: C:\Users\ ****\workspace\Pokemon\src\tile-24.png" and gone to that location and the image shows up.

Comment: Have you tried? `createImageIcon("./src/tile"+"-"+images[i][j]+".png");`

Comment: @chicagochillin [works](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of posting a a whole bunch of code and not specifying the error message you get in your question, you could start with a simple code snippet (I neglect imports, ... since I am too lazy to fire up my IDE)

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
  File file = new File( "C:...");//with the path you use in your code
  System.out.println( file.exists() );
}
```

This is about what you need to discover/debug your problem. Then you can start on converting it to a relative path.

Answer (score 1):

If the resources are inherently part of the app. (an embedded application resource) and not for write, they should be added to a Jar on the application's run-time class-path and accessed via URL obtained from `Class.getResource()`.  It would work something like:

```
URL urlToMap1 = this.getClass().getResource("/src/map1.txt");
```

You'd need to check the exact path in the Jar that resource ends up at, and reference it from the root of the Jar (`/`) then the path within the Jar (`src/map1.txt`).